# Confusing rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

**Question:**

> If $$x = \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}+1}$$ Then find value of, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*(\frac{x+2}{x-2}+\frac{x+2\sqrt{2}}{x - 2\sqrt{2}})$$

**My approach:**

I rationalized the value of $x$ to be $8-4\sqrt{2}$, then substituted values to get:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}* (\frac{10 - 4\sqrt{2}}{6 - 4\sqrt{2}}+\frac{8-6\sqrt{2}}{8-2\sqrt{2}})$$

and solved until I got:

$$\frac{24-15\sqrt{2}}{8\sqrt{2}-11}$$

But this doesn't seem to please the options.

Can anyone please guide me on how to approach this problem (not all the steps, that would be huge, but the beginning steps or any hints).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't checked your intermediate math, but perhaps you are expected to rationalize the denominator in your final answer?

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Well I already did that, and got $8 − 4\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @GaurangTandon $8-4\sqrt 2$ is the rationalization of $8$. But you can also rationalize the final result.

Comment: Can't see any short cuts but you have made an error with the fraction $$\frac{8-6\sqrt2}{8-2\sqrt2}\ ,$$ it should be the other way up.

Comment: @David well except componedo and dividendo. that's a neat shortcut here.

Comment: Yes, read that answer after I posted the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac x2=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+1}$$

Applying Componendo & Dividendo, $$\frac{x+2}{x-2}=\frac{2\sqrt2+(\sqrt2+1)}{2\sqrt2-(\sqrt2+1)}=\frac{3\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt2-1}=\frac{(3\sqrt2+1)(\sqrt2+1)}{2-1}$$

$$=7+4\sqrt2$$

Similarly, $$\frac x{2\sqrt2}=\frac2{\sqrt2+1}$$

Apply Componendo & Dividendo again

Comment: Well, I don't understand. If this answer was for rationalizing $x$, then I have already done that. And got value of $8-4\sqrt{2}$. Please clarify a bit more.

Comment: @GaurangTandon no. in this answer, he has shown how to obtain the values of $(x+2)/(x-2)$ and $(x+2\sqrt{2})/(x-2\sqrt{2})$ directly without obtaining $x$. In this was you can just substitute into your equation.

Comment: @GaurangTandon As should be recognizable from the equations, lab computes one of the constituents of the expression in question, namely $\frac{x+2}{x-2}$, and obtains a rationalized (partial) result. Btw, the trick behind this is that $\frac ab=\frac cd$ implies $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c+d}{c-d}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh, I am really a newbie ! Thanks !

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Thank you for the hints! I will compute the rest myself.

Comment: @GaurangTandon, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447978/if-p-frac4-sin-theta-cos-theta-sin-theta-cos-theta-find-the-value-of,    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628314/solving-an-irrational-equation    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264927/find-the-acute-angle-x-for-tan-x-tanx10-circ-tanx20-circ-tanx30

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks for the links!